# Como desabilitar um datatables na hora da impressão

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-datatables

A pagina tem um datatables https://datatables.net/, gostaria de ocultar os itens que é criados por ele na hora da impressão, exemplo: campo de pesquisa, paginação etc.

Meu datatable está dessa forma:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#minhaTabela').DataTable({
            "language": {
                "lengthMenu": "Mostrando _MENU_ registros por página",
                "zeroRecords": "Nada encontrado",
                "info": "Mostrando página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
                "infoEmpty": "Nenhum registro disponível",
                "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de _MAX_ registros no total)",



                "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
                "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
                "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
                "sInfoPostFix": "",
                "sInfoThousands": ".",
                "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página",
                "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
                "sProcessing": "Processando...",
                "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                "sSearch": "Pesquisar",
                "oPaginate": {
                    "sNext": "Próximo",
                    "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                    "sFirst": "Primeiro",
                    "sLast": "Último"
                },
                "oAria": {
                    "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
                    "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
                }

            }
        });
    });


</script>
```

Para fazer a impressão estou usando o print do css e coloquei dessa forma para ocultar mais não funcionou.

```
  .lengthMenu,
    .zeroRecords,
    .info,
    .infoEmpty,
    .infoFiltered,
    .sEmptyTable,
    .sInfo,
    .sInfoEmpty,
    .sInfoFiltered,
    .sInfoPostFix,
    .sInfoThousands,
    .sLengthMenu,
    .sLoadingRecords,
    .sProcessing,
    .sZeroRecords,
    .sSearch,
    .oPaginate,
    .oAria {
        display: none;
    }
```

Gostaria de ocultar também o nome da janela e o rodapé que a função pega do navegador.

Comment: Cara no seu css o nome da classe tem que ter um ponto antes, o nome da classe começa com um **`. `**! tipo `.nome { css }`

Comment: @hugocsl Então, esqueci desse detalhe na hora de publicar aqui rsrs, mas infelizmente ainda não é isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara o rodapé e o link acho que vc não consegue apagar, pq é da configuração da impressora **acho que** vc não consegue mudar isso com CSS

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Configuração que o usuário faz

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Mas vc pode fazer uma **gambiarra** que vai "encobrir" as informações que vc não quer. Basta vc mudar os valores default das margens de impressão, para isso use essa regra:

```
  @page {
    size: A4;  
    margin: 15pt 0pt 25pt;
  }
```

Esse é o print que consegui com esse css acima:

**OBS:** Não funciona caso o conteúdo não ocupe a página inteira, pois ele não vai "encobrir" o rodapé. Porém se o seu `container` estiver com `display flex` vc pode criar uma `div` vazia no final de tudo com `flex:1` assim ela vai cobrir o espaço restante do container cobrindo o rodapé.

**Sem** a `div` com `flex:1` no final
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Com** a `div` vazia com `flex:1` no final
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Sobre remover outros elemento no `print`**

Mas sobre os campos que quer remover na impressão, no seu css inclua isso:

```
@media only print {
    .dataTables_length,
    .dataTables_filter,
    .dataTables_info,
    .dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

A impressão da tabela deve ficar como na imagem abaixo retirada direito do site que vc citou na pergunta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: coloquei dessa forma no meu print css, mas não funcionou. Mas acho que já sei o que pode ter acontecido, fiz a tradução do itens e inserir dentro da função, acredito que os nomes estão diferente, vou verificar e já te dou um retorno. Mas desde já agradeço por me ajudar.

Comment: @mba cara se vc mudou o nome das classes bosta mudar para os nomes que vc substitui ai, ou então usar pelo ID caso vc tenha colocado algum nesses elementos. Tb editei a resposta com uma solução que pode te servir para resolver o problema do rodapé...

Comment: Editei minha pergunta, colocando o código como estou usando, devo esta esquecendo alguma coisa. Não tem base..rsrs

Comment: @mba vc viu o comentário que fiz lá encima depois que vc editou? Tem que colocar um . antes do nome das classes no css. Tb editei a minha resposta com vários detalhes sobre como esconder o rodapé original mudando as margins de impressão...

Comment: vi sim, mas infelizmente ainda não é isso.

Comment: @mba vai no Chrome clica com o btn direito do mous no elemento que quer excluir e selecione no menu que vai abrir Inspecionar, ou Inspect, o DevToos vai abrir mostrando o elemento que vc clicou. Veja qual é o nome da classe dele ou se ele tem um ID. Cope e cole essa .classe ou #id no seu css dentro da regra `@media only print { .classe {display: none !important;} #id{display: none !important;} }`

Comment: valeu pela dica, os nomes estava bem parecido como você tinha mencionado antes, olha para vc ver: `.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_processing, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate {
        display: none !important;
    }` Por causa do   ` .dataTables_wrapper` que não estava funcionando. Vou tentar a dica rodapé. Obrigado

Comment: @mba tinha que dar certo uai! Que bom que resolveu!

Comment: Então, graças a sua ajuda. Valeu mano. Abraços.